# Raspberry firmware on micro sd card; file system format

Tags: boot, firmware

I am downloading the firmware from here

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware

and I would like to know, what are the steps to burn the firmware on the micro SD card? Unfortunately, there is no description available in the wiki.

When I insert the pre built SD Card that came with the Raspberry hardware, it shows me two paritions: boot and kernel.

Can anyone tell me the file system format and which files go to which partition? Basically I want to start every thing from scratch.

Comment: Though it covers NOOBS and not plain Raspbian without NOOBS, [NOOBS Partitioning Explained](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained) is a useful overview of how a Pi boot partition works. There's also some more detailed information on booting in general in the [bootmodes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I realised that I can use a current Raspberry to see the format.

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7969 MB, 7969177600 bytes
4 heads, 16      sectors/track,     243200 cylinders, total 15564800 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x000c45c9

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA) 
/dev/mmcblk0p2          122880     6399999     3138560   83  Linux
```

lsblk gives me the following:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0    56M  0 part /boot
-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0     3G  0 part /
```

So, it means 56M is reserved for boot partition and should be the first parition formatted in FAT32 and 3G is formatted in File system Linux ( I guess ext4 ).

I just need to copy the bootcode.bin, kernel.img and other stuffs ( still to find out the minimum requirement to boot ) in the boot parition and the Linux parition contains the rest of the linux directory tree - usr, lib etc.

Comment: you are almost correct, but the boot partition is FAT32, with the other partition containing `usr` `lib` etc. on the latest distros this is usually ext3 or ext4, easiest way to get latest firmware is to just boot it and run `rpi-update` as per @Ricardo answer, but if you insist on doing it manually then put card into another machine and drop the files into the boot partition

Comment: Oh yes sorry. I completely reversed Linux and FAT32. Updating my post to write the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply download the [latest Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and burn it on the SD Card using [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) as recommended by the Foundation.

Then at your own risk, you could update the Firmware using [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update).

Comment: But I wanted to do something from scratch, learning every process on the way. Apart from that I am a linux user.